# Flutter :How to update the path of the image i selected from the gallery automatically?:flutter

Tags: flutter, image, path, picker

Flutter
I used package image picker to selected image from galary and save the path of the image in firestore as String, But when the path of image change in the phone the image disapper from app and the path of image dont update in the firestore
What the Solution
Flutter

Comment: Why save the image path? Wouldn't the right thing be to save the image and use the url?

Comment: Ok how  to save the image and use url how can I do that

Comment: Use [firebase_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_storage/example) to save the image. After the upload you retrieve the image link and finally save the image link in the firestore.